# What does "MyProject.Repository.EF.AccountRepository' does not implement interface member" really mean?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to implement an child interface using an Abstract class for most of the methods and a child of this abstract class to implement the missing methods. But the compiler keeping throwing those errors: "Foo.Bar' does not implement interface member".
After long hours staring at the code and reading tonnes of similar problems here on StackOverflow, I keep not seeing where the problem is. :S

**Those are some of the "zillion" errors in my code I am having and I don't really see what is happening.**

```
Error 2   
'MyProject.Repository.EF.AccountRepository' does not implement interface member 'MyProject.Entities.IRepository<MyProject.Entities.Account,int>.FindAll()'. 
'MyProject.Repository.EF.RepositoryBase<MyProject.Repository.EF.Account,int>.FindAll()' cannot implement 'MyProject.Entities.IRepository<MyProject.Entities.Account,int>.FindAll()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Entities.Account>'.  
D:\Projects\WebProjects\MyProject\MyProject.Repository.EF\AccountRepository.cs  5   18  MyProject.Repository.EF
```

//

**And this is the code**

//

**// Repository interface**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace MyProject.Entities 
{
    public interface IRepository<T, EntityKey> {
        void Save();
        void Add(T entity);
        void Remove(T entity);

        T FindBy(EntityKey id);
        IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query);
        IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query, int index, int count);
        IEnumerable<T> FindAll();
    }
}
```

//

**// "Child" interface**

```
namespace MyProject.Entities 
{
    public interface IAccountRepository : IRepository<Account, int> {
    }
}
```

//

**// Abstract class that implement almost every method from the interface and declare two of then abstract to be implemented by a child class**

```
using MyProject.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace MyProject.Repository.EF 
{
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T, EntityKey> : IRepository<T, EntityKey> where T : class {

        private IQueryable<T> objectSet;
        protected MyProjectEntitiesContext Context;

        public abstract string GetEntitySetName();
        public abstract T FindBy(EntityKey id);

        public IQueryable<T> ObjectSet
        {
            get { return objectSet; }
            set { objectSet = value; }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            this.Context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            this.Context.AddObject(this.GetEntitySetName(), entity);
        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            this.Context.DeleteObject(entity);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindAll()
        {
            return this.ObjectSet;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
        {
            return this.ObjectSet.Where(query);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query, int index, int count)
        {
            return this.FindBy(query).Skip(index).Take(count);
        }
    }
}
```

//

**// Here the two missing methods are being implemented**

```
using System.Linq;
using MyProject.Entities;

namespace MyProject.Repository.EF {
    public class AccountRepository : RepositoryBase<Account, int>, IAccountRepository {
        public AccountRepository()
        {
            this.Context = MyProjectEntitiesFactory.GetDatacontext();
            this.ObjectSet = this.Context.Accounts;
        }

        public override string GetEntitySetName()
        {
            return this.Context.Accounts.EntitySet.Name;
        }

        public override Account FindBy(int id)
        {
            return this.ObjectSet.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have two different `Account` classes? One at `MyProject.Repository.EF.Account` and one at `MyProject.Entities.Account`? EDIT: I think your `IAccountRepository` is using one version of `Account` while your `AccountRepository` (class) is using the other.

Comment: The code compiles just fine (with `throw new NotImplementedException()`s) in the methods, so I think @ChrisSinclair is right. Actually pretty much what the error says: _"'MyProject.Repository.EF.RepositoryBase< **MyProject.Repository.EF.Account** ,int>.FindAll()' cannot implement 'MyProject.Entities.IRepository< **MyProject.Entities.Account** ,int>.FindAll()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Entities.Account>'."_.

Comment: I don't really see what you mean. I only have one entity called account if it is what you're saying

Comment: @MarcSJ You have two classes defined with the same name "Account" but with different namespaces. Is this intended/by design? If not, then update your `AccountRepository` (or `IAccountRepository`) to properly point to the class in the proper namespace.

Comment: Yes, the problem was exactly that. I used Entity to create a class diagram in the ***MyProject.Repository.EF*** namespace but EF create the classes for each entity that conflicted with the ones from ***MyProject.Model***. So I removed the ones from ***MyProject.Repository.EF*** to solve the problem. You could post it as an answer so I can choose it as the answer for my question.